# Using leaflet.js with a non-geo map (gdal2tiles.py)

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to use Leaflet.js to access a non-geo (scanned image ...) map, which I tiled using `gdal2tiles.py -p raster`.  But I absolutely can't get it to work:  I see Leaflet requesting URLs with negative coordinates and non-existent ones.  (Such as: `/3/-1/8.png` ...)

The map in question is 1162 pixels wide and 700 pixels high.

The `tilemapresource.xml` file generated by `gdal2tiles` says, among other things:
`<BoundingBox minx="0.0" miny="-700.0" maxx="1162.0" maxy="0.0"/>
 <Origin x="0.0" y="-700.0"/>`

So, as you can see, the Y coordinates range from a negative number to zero, and the X range from zero to a positive number.  (That's just the way that `gdal2tiles.py` decided to do it, I guess.)

I am using `CRS.Simple` like all the documents say to do, and I'm setting the bounds to `SouthWest=(-700,0), NorthEast=(0,1162)`, admitting to be already mightily-confused when I see other examples that seem to be reversing the second (Lng) coordinate.

*(I realized that "Lat" corresponds to "Y" and "Lng" to "X.")*

Equally puzzling to me is that when I `unproject` the Southwest and Northeast points using the max-zoom, I get `LatLng(-36.3125, -21.875)` for SouthWest.  I don't know why.  *(Again, I am using `CRS.Simple` ...)*

Experimentally, I set "tms: false" on the tile-layer, which caused *something* to show up, but now the display's doing the most amazing thing: entirely on its own, it's "ping-ponging" back and forth along a line from roughly the middle of the right-hand margin down-and-left to the middle of the bottom, and back.

I know I've been whacking at this thing for too long today...

Comment: I guess I'm most-confused when I do this in the debugger of any browser:  `L.CRS.Simple.pointToLatLng(new L.Point(10,10), 3)` ... and what I get in response is `Lat(-1.25, 1.25)`, which seems to me basically that it is *not* "translating lat,lng to x,y directly" as implied by http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#icrs ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found it.  (And, since I wound up asking this question twice, let me answer it in both places.)

> Add *all* of the layers that you are going to use on your map, when you call the Map object's constructor, using the `layers` option.

In other words, do *not* do as I was doing:  try to set up the various layers first, then add them to the map.  The map needs to know about the layers, and the layers need to know about the map, right from the start. So, add them, *then* configure them as you need.

Otherwise, "strange and default things may happen."  For example, although I specified the `Simple` CRS, that's not what I effectively wound-up with.  It appears that the various objects (map, layers), "talk to one another" quite a bit with this library, and they don't expect to be orphans.

(Some of the "strange things" that can happen are, in fact, *bizarre* ... like:  a tiny version of the map, *ping-ponging* between "about three o'clock" and "about six o'clock" and back again.  A funny and entertaining thing to look at, *unless* you don't yet know why it's happening, nor how to stop it! *Whew!* )

The design of "leaflet.js" certainly isn't *wrong,* to be sure, but it has some unpleasant surprises for the unwary.  (Like me.)  Hope this helps.